# Check if a method exists from an object nested using lodash

Tags: javascript, json, object, data-structures, lodash

For example,

check if `isCourage()` method exist in such object.

```
puppy {

  ...

  goldenRetriever {

     ...

     hasCourage(){ ... }

  }

}
```

Lodash can do the trick but i'm not sure which method should i use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lodash you have a few functions that might be helpful to you:

You can use [`_.isFunction`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isFunction) with [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get):

```js
let obj = {
  foo:{
    bar:{
      fooBar: function(b) { return b }
    }
  }
}

console.log(_.isFunction(_.get(obj,'foo.bar.fooBar')))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use [`_.result`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#result) to get the value right away and `not care` really if it is or not a function. `_.result` would walk the path executing anything that **is a function** and return the final value:

```js
let obj = {
  foo:{
    bar:{
      fooBar: function(b='yay') { return b }
    }
  }
}

console.log(_.result(obj, 'foo.bar.fooBar'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh that is quite succint and elegant

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
_.get(puppy,'bar.goldenRetrieve.foo.hasCorauge.constructor') === Function
```

(bar and foo are examples since `...` would be confusing and .contructor should return Function if it is a function...)

```js
let obj = {
  foo:{
    bar:{
      myFn:function(b){return b;}
    }
  }
}

console.log(_.get(obj,'foo.bar.myFn.constructor')===Function);
console.log(_.get(obj,'foo.bar.myFn2.constructor')===Function);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: lodash like your answer was awesome. Thanks.